# Can I use footer element in header element

Tags: html

Can ı use footer element in header element.

```
 <header>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  <footer>
    <img src="/src/images/clouds-1440w-desktop.jpg" alt="">
  </footer>
</header>
```

Comment: Technically, yes. But [semantically](https://web.dev/learn/html/headings-and-sections/), that doesn't make sense, and so you shouldn't. Can you elaborate your question with why you would want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

No. The [definition of the `header` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-header-element) forbids `footer` descendants:

> Content model:
>
> [Flow content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content-2), but with no `header` or `footer` element descendants.

Comment: To be clear, the HTML parser won't reject nesting a `footer` within a `header`, but it wouldn't be semantic HTML.

Comment: Semantics aside, it won’t be **valid** HTML and you would be depending on error recovery rules.